# My TestInitialized class is invisible to my test

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I'm trying to follow the advice of the sage Answermen re: moving my class instantiation to the TestInitialize method:

```
        [TestInitialize()]
        public void MyTestInitialize()
        {
            MessageClass target = new MessageClass();
        }

. . .

        [TestMethod()]
        public void SetMessageTypeSubcodeTest()
    ...
            target.SetMessageTypeSubcode(AMessageTypeSubcode); // <- here
```

...but I'm getting, *"The name 'target' does not exist in the current context"* above.

How can I make "target" visible to my test method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your target object is defined in a local scope. Make it a field instead of a local variable so other class methods can access it.

```
class TestClass
{
    MessageClass _target;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
        _target = new MessageClass();
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void SetMessageTypeSubcodeTest()
    {
        _target.SetMessageTypeSubcode(AMessageTypeSubcode);
    }
}
```

Comment: That should have been obvious, but in my defense, I thought maybe the testing framework would work some magic behind the scenes to know that "target" (after all, it placed that identifier there) pointed to the class under test.